# iOS app icon with transparent background showing black background on device

Tags: ios, background, icons, transparency

I have added an icon to my app. It has rounded edges and no background. The problem is that when I run an app on my device (iPhone 5) the icon has a black background behind the edges as if it wasn't transparent. Any solutions?

Comment: There should be no transparency in the image

Comment: Could you add a screenshot @Fengson, it would be useful to know if it's the same problem we're experiencing or not?

Comment: How did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

From the apple developer website after a quick search:

> Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can appear to float on a black background, which tends to look especially unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Edit: Also, check the related questions before you confirm your post - [Is is possible to use transparency in an iPhone app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959864/is-is-possible-to-use-transparency-in-an-iphone-app-icon?rq=1)

Comment: Funny how often the solution to Apple problems is to just stop trying to be creative. +1 for the info, though.

Answer (score 8):

On IOS use just square icons, if you use rounder icons you will have black margin black background.