# How to remove black screen on AppIcon - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, background, ios9, assets

I have my png AppIcon:

[image]

When I put this image in **Assets.xcassets** I see on my device an icon with a black background. I have seen some posts about this:

Example: [iOS app icon with transparent background showing black background on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858501/ios-app-icon-with-transparent-background-showing-black-background-on-device)

I have only this image, I can modify this to remove the black background?

Comment: Try running it in simulator or device.
Does the app icon still have the black background?

Comment: yes, I want to add some color instead of transparent but I don't know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove transparency from image. App icons should be fully opaque.