# Ignore increased color scheme contrast for SwiftUI Color or View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The settings options in my app are styled with an icon on a solid colour background and a text label next to them, similar to the items in Apple's iOS Settings app:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    Image(...)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .frame(width: 28, height: 28, alignment: .center)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6, style: .continuous)
        .fill(Color.blue)) // Color may be a property instead, simplified here.
    .accessibility(hidden: true)

    Text(title)
        .font(.system(
            size: 16,
            weight: .medium,
            design: .rounded))
        .padding(.leading)
}
```

However, I've noticed that the background color ([SwiftUI Color](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color)) for my icon views change when the system 'Increase Contrast' accessibility option is enabled, whereas the background colour of Apple's Settings icons do not. As an example, `Color.orange` looks more like a red color when 'Increase Contrast' is enabled.

I'd therefore like to ignore the current color scheme's contrast setting ([`ColorSchemeContrast` environment value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/colorschemecontrast)) if it's set to `.increased`, just for the background colour of my icon view.

Unfortunately, using the environment modifier gives an error, as `.colorSchemeContrast` is not a writable property:
`.environment(\.colorSchemeContrast, .standard)`. This is similarly documented by Apple: *"Your app cannot override the user’s choice.".*

I'm only trying to avoid specific small areas of colour changing when contrast is increased, as Apple themselves do, so I can only assume there should be some way of achieving this.

Is there any other way to work around this issue?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/22858567/3441734

Comment: Thanks @user3441734, but that question and answer aren't relevant to this question – I'm trying to ignore contrast for a SwiftUI `Color` or `View` as a whole, which may or may not even have an image. Edited my question more to clarify

Comment: why not define your own color?

Comment: I’d like to be able to use the built-in system colours that automatically adapt between light and dark mode. Could define my own, but would have to scrape the system colour values and potentially be out of sync if they changed. Still curious if there’s a technique I’m missing, otherwise I’ll likely just leave my colours to change in high contrast mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer might come late, but I've stumbled into this problem myself and found a solution.

**Supporting Light & Dark modus with custom colors**

First of all, whenever you want to use custom colors and support both Light & Dark modus, It's always a good idea to create a custom color in your Asset library:

- Go to your asset library (Usually images.xcassets)
- Click + in the Assets Navigator
- Select 'Color Set' and give your new color a name
- In the inspector area (right of the screen), select the Attributes Inspector, and set 'Appearances' to 'Any, Light, Dark'. This will allow you to provide a color for all appearances.

If you then use `Color("testColor")` or `UIColor(named: testColor)`, you'll see that your color automatically adapts light & dark mode

**Anticipating for High Contrast**

When users enable High Contrast in their system accessibility settings, you'll notice that your colors don't anticipate on both light & dark modus anymore. Don't worry though, enabling this is a matter of simply checking a checkbox:

- Go to your asset library
- Select the color for which you want to support high system contrast
- Check the 'High Contrast' Checkbox

This allow you to define another custom color for high system contrast, but by default it just copies the colors you already defined earlier.

Comment: Thanks @Joris416 – well explained, this seems like the best approach. In the comments on my original question I'd wondered if there was another route (or modifier) around this, but it looks like a custom asset works well.